# Writing to text based exe using subprocess

Tags: python, subprocess, popen

Trying to write to a text based exe file ([ITU NeQuick2 model](https://www.itu.int/dms_pubrec/itu-r/rec/p/R-REC-P.531-12-201309-S!!PDF-E.pdf)) that takes two input lines for example

```
$$$ 
Program starts
input 1 :
input 2 :
done
$$$
```

Currently I have this code

```
prog = subprocess.Popen(filepath,stdout=subprocess.PIPE, stderr=subprocess.PIPE, text=True)
    
output, error = prog.communicate(input = "45,45,100\n")
print(output)
```

Which currently prints

```
$$$ 
Program starts
input 1 :
$$$
```

However using

```
prog = subprocess.run([filepath], capture_output= True,input="45,45,1000", encoding="utf-8")
```

results in

```
$$$ 
Program starts
input 1 :
input 2 :
$$$
```

Without "entering" the last input but it enters the first how do I get it to "enter" the second line and compute?

I have also tried `"45,45,1000\n34,34,10000` to no success
Also tried "45,45,1000\n34,34,10000\n" to the same success as the previous attempt

Comment: Use `pexpect` to control an interactive application. You'll probably run into buffering problems if you try to do it using `subprocess`.

Comment: What is the other program?  You should show us the source.  You're only sending one input line here.

Comment: `input='first value\nsecond value\n` could work, too. This is probably a duplicate

Comment: For `input="45,45,1000"`, because you aren't piping into the subprocess, after the program exhausts the first line (input 1), future reads will read End of File (EOF). Typically that's represented by the read() function giving a 0-byte string. So the `input 2` will get the string `""`, and do whatever it wants to with that, either detecting that it reached EOF or just treating it as a valid input

Comment: Can you try `"45,45,1000\n34,34,10000\n"`? With the added newline at the end? Inputs often work in [Canonical mode](https://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Canonical-or-Not.html), where they won't do anything until they reach a new line, so it could be that your code is waiting for the final newline to reach the `done` stage.